# Checking whether union of two languages is regular

Tags: automata, regular-languages, proof-techniques

How to check if

$L = \{c^ka^nb^n \mid k>0 \wedge n\geqslant0\} \cup \{a, b\}^*$

is regular ,where

$L_1 = \{c^ka^nb^n \mid k > 0 \wedge n\geqslant0\}$ is clearly not regular and $L_2 = \{a, b\}^*$ is... ?

Comment: Closure under union

Comment: so when L1 is not regular, and L is the union of L1 and L2 , automaticly L isn't regular ?

Comment: Correct! You cannot build (e.g. DFA) the union of a regular and non-regular language.

Comment: Wrong. For example, $\{a^nb^n \mid n \geq 0\} \cup a^*b^*$ is regular.

Comment: Look for a sub-language easy to prove non-regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L$ were regular than so would the following language be:
$$L \cap ca^*b^* = \{ ca^nb^n \mid n \geq 0 \}.$$
You can show that the latter language is not regular in various ways.

Comment: Thank you for editing the post, ill learn to use the website so i can make better posts! And thanks for the suggestion!